# 4-layer board in PCB Editor - do I need custom vias?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design

I routed a 4-layer board using the default via. When I put in my ground and VCC planes the vias had no clearance. How do I fix it? Do I have to make my own vias? (I thought it was automatic). Next time I will draw the inner ground and VCC planes before I route. Geeezzz.

Comment: Have you set up the plane fill correctly? You need to tell it what net it should be connected to, what clearance you want, whether to use reliefs or not, etc. Also, remember it will connect to all the vias that are on the same net.

Comment: There was a prompt for what net for the plane, but I didn't see where to set clearance, or reliefs for the plane. I know how to set those in pad designer for through-holes.

Comment: Hmmm, has to be there somewhere. Sorry I can't help more as I don't use PCB Editor (what package is it part of? who makes it?)

Comment: @OliGlaser I believe he's talking about Altium

Comment: Cadence. My company gives me a license to learn provided I don't bug them for help. I just had a thought, should I change the stackup type from plane to conductor?

Comment: If it's like Altium, IIRC you set up the plane clearances, etc, in the design rules. I would imagine it should be kept set to plane, although no harm in trying :-)

Comment: I don't know PCB Editor either, but FWIW, programs usually make a difference between copper pours (which won't care about the vias) and "electrical" planes. If it asked for a net, it does sound like it's supposed to work like you think though.. but check if there are other items/tools to make plane-like stuff :)

Comment: @BSEE  Are you using the PCB Editor, which is a part of OrCAD package?  If so, which version do you have?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up changing the layer type to conductor and changing the plane shape to dynamic copper and it worked. There was clearance around the vias for thelayers they were not attached too.